# How to use debounce function with CanJS DefineMap view-model method?

Tags: javascript, viewmodel, canjs, debouncing, canjs-component

I'm trying to use lodash `_.debounce` function for `canjs` `DefineMap` view-model method but it seems that `this` is tricky even I tried to do it in the `init` method but without success:

```
export const ViewModel = DefineMap.extend({
 init() {
  this.myMethod = _.debounce(this.myMethod, 200)
 },
 myMethod() {
  // cool stuff here
 }
})
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because DefineMap's are sealed by default, and you likely want independent throttling with respect to individual instances of `ViewModel`, you want to do it like this:

```
var time = new Date();

var ViewModel = can.DefineMap.extend({
 id: "number",
 myMethod: {
   type: "any",
   default(){

     var fn = _.debounce(function(){
       console.log(this.id+" says Hi at "+(new Date() - time))
     },100);
     return fn;
   }
 }
});
```

This basically sets the `myMethod` property to a debounced function.  You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/nekelak/edit?html,js,console